# How to change opacity of date type placeholder text?

Tags: html, css

[Registration Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyPvF.png)

I am using:

```
<span class="input input--isao"> <input class="input__field input__field--isao" type="date" id="dateofbirth" name="dateofbirth"/> <label class="input__label input__label--isao" for="dateofbirth" data-content="Date of Birth"> <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--isao">Date of Birth</span> </label> </span>

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity:  0.4;
}
```

How do I get the placeholder text for the date to also be 0.4 opacity. The placeholder yyyy-mm-dd is automatic, not inputted by me. Pls see image.

Comment: You should at leat provide the HTML code used to create the date element. Is it a plugin?

Comment: Added your code to the question. How does the placeholder get added? What plugin _are_ you using? The issue is, is it an _actual placeholder attribute_ or is it a plugin that adds that value until the field receives focus and then removes it, just to readd it when the field loses focus and is empty...? That would use a different approach to styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Datable.js](http://invot.github.io/datable.js/) query plugin it mask the text input as date input

Comment: You potentially could but that does not solve the question at hand.